# SQL Server: How to SELECT the Many-to-Many Values of two Columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is there a way to SELECT only the Many-to-Many records based on 2 columns in a table. I do not want to select the N:1, 1:1 and N:1 values in the dataset, but only the ones that are N:N. This means I only want to SELECT the records of which a value in Column1 has multiple related values in Column2, but some (or all) of those values in Column2 also have multiple related values in Column1.

Underneath I have a table, in which I already show in Column `Relationship`, what I am looking for. So I only want to be able to SELECT record 8. Of course without the use of Column `Relationship`, since I have manually added that to understand what I try to say.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestManytoMany;
CREATE TABLE TestManytoMany
(Column1 nvarchar NULL,
Column2 nvarchar NULL,
Relationship nvarchar(4) NULL);
INSERT INTO TestManytoMany
VALUES
('A','1','n:1')
,('A','2','n:1')
,('A','3','n:1')
,('B','4','1:n')
,('C','4','1:n')
,('D','5','1:1')
,('E','6','n:1')
,('E','7','n:n')
,('F','7','1:n')
SELECT * FROM TestManytoMany
```

I couldn't find anything alike on the internet, maybe someone has any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Your `F, 7` row is only `1:n`, I assume this is a typo?

Comment: Also, is the data in the first two columns unique in any way or do you have duplicates that should also be considered for the `n:n` check?

Comment: If that's the case, then `E, 6` is `n:1` and only `E, 7` is `n:n`. These should indeed be differently labeled, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: There might be entirely duplicate records in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that will provide the output you need (though I am not sure how well it would perform on larger datasets) is to use `count`s over `partition` windows:

## Query

```
declare @TestManytoMany table(Column1 nvarchar(5)
                             ,Column2 nvarchar(5)
                             ,Relationship nvarchar(4)
                             );
insert into @TestManytoMany
values
 ('A','1','n:1')
,('A','2','n:1')
,('A','3','n:1')
,('B','4','1:n')
,('C','4','1:n')
,('D','5','1:1')
,('E','6','n:1')
,('E','7','n:n')
,('F','7','1:n')
;

with c as
(
    select *
          ,count(1) over (partition by Column1) as c1c
          ,count(1) over (partition by Column2) as c2c
    from @TestManytoMany as t
)
select Column1
      ,Column2
from c
where c1c > 1
    and c2c > 1;
```

---

## Output

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| E | 7 |

Comment: for 5 million records it was done within a second! Thanks, the code makes a lot of sense to me.